# Flutter : After setting newLatLngBounds Marker tap event not working on first click

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, flutter

I have facing issue related to google map flutter, I am using below lib to load Map.

**dependencies:**

**google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.24+1**

Issue by step;

1. Load map with Marker.
2. Tap on Marker, it's auto center (Working perfectly as default behavior)
3. After set **newLatLngBounds** by clicking button newLatLngBounds
4. Then click to Marker, First Marker click not working (means not
   going to marker in the center in Map), click a second time on a marker
   tap is working and Map auto center as step-2.

Why Marker first tap event not working after set the **newLatLngBounds**

```
// Copyright 2018 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

import 'page.dart';

class AnimateCameraPage extends Page {
  AnimateCameraPage()
      : super(const Icon(Icons.map), 'Camera control, animated');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const AnimateCamera();
  }
}

class AnimateCamera extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimateCamera();
  @override
  State createState() => AnimateCameraState();
}

class AnimateCameraState extends State<AnimateCamera> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  LatLng _kMapCenter = LatLng(-27.470030, 153.022980);

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 300.0,
            height: 200.0,
            child: GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              markers: _createMarker(),
              initialCameraPosition:
                  const CameraPosition(target: LatLng(0.0, 0.0)),
              onTap: (tap) {
                print("GoogleMap Tap");
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    mapController.animateCamera(
                      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                        const CameraPosition(
                          bearing: 270.0,
                          target: LatLng(51.5160895, -0.1294527),
                          tilt: 30.0,
                          zoom: 17.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('newCameraPosition'),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    mapController.animateCamera(
                      CameraUpdate.newLatLng(
                        const LatLng(56.1725505, 10.1850512),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('newLatLng'),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    mapController.animateCamera(
                      CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(
                        LatLngBounds(
                          southwest: const LatLng(-38.483935, 113.248673),
                          northeast: const LatLng(-8.982446, 153.823821),
                        ),
                        10.0,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('newLatLngBounds'),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    mapController.animateCamera(
                      CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(
                        const LatLng(37.4231613, -122.087159),
                        11.0,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('newLatLngZoom'),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    mapController.animateCamera(
                      CameraUpdate.scrollBy(150.0, -225.0),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('scrollBy'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    mapController.animateCamera(
                      CameraUpdate.zoomBy(
                        -0.5,
                        const Offset(30.0, 20.0),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('zoomBy with focus'),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    mapController.animateCamera(
                      CameraUpdate.zoomBy(-0.5),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('zoomBy'),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    mapController.animateCamera(
                      CameraUpdate.zoomIn(),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('zoomIn'),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    mapController.animateCamera(
                      CameraUpdate.zoomOut(),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('zoomOut'),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    mapController.animateCamera(
                      CameraUpdate.zoomTo(16.0),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('zoomTo'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Set<Marker> _createMarker() {
    // https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28312
    // ignore: prefer_collection_literals
    return <Marker>[
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("marker_1"),
        position: _kMapCenter,
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
        onTap: () {
          print("Marker Tap");
        },
      ),
    ].toSet();
  }
}
```

Comment: it occur only ios platform ?

Comment: @dangngocduc Yes, in iOS only, Android working perfectly.

Comment: I have a similar issue on IOS. I change animateCamera to moveCamera on IOS to hotfix.

Comment: @dangngocduc Nop, moveCamera also not working, we need to click 2 times marker that is works :(